# Bugs em algoritmo que criptografa texto

Tags: c, criptografia

Estou escrevendo um algoritmo que criptografa texto usando uma palavra como senha, cifra de Vigenère. Caracteres maiúsculos e minúsculos devem criptografar, caracteres especiais e números devem ser ignorados. Minhas dúvidas:

- Ao executar o programa, digitar a senha e posteriormente o texto,
  acontece o erro *Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada)*. Por
  quê?
- O código não está funcionando, como melhorá-lo?

**código:**

```
#include<cc50.h> // BIBLIOTECA DO CURSO QUE ESTOU FAZENDO.
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char argv[])
{

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Erro 1. Digite uma palavra na linha de comando.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Texto a ser criptografado:\n");
    string texto = GetString();

    int k = 0;
    int l = strlen(texto);
    int m = strlen(argv);

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        k = atoi(argv[j]);
        if (j > m) // SE O CONTADOR J FOR MAIOR QUE A QUANTIDADE DE CARACTERES DA SENHA, REDEFINE J e K PARA 0.
            {
            j = 0;
            k = 0;
            }
        else if (texto[i] >= 65 && texto[i] <= 90)
            {
            texto[i] = (((texto[i] - 65) + k) % 26) + 65;
            j++;
            }
        else if (texto[i] >= 97 && texto[i] <= 122)
            {
            texto[i] = (((texto[i] - 97) + k) % 26) + 97;
            j++;
            }
        else;
        printf("%c", texto[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Não precisa ser uma grande resposta, pequenas dicas que me guie a solução serve, pois já estou a algumas semanas preso a este problema.

Comment: Pode ser mais especifico qual o erro ? E em que linha o mesmo acontece

Comment: Qual o objetivo desta linha `k = atoi(argv[j]);` ? `argv` supostamente só tem uma string para além do nome do executavel, logo rapidamente falha ai se o indice passar o `1`. Já para não dizer que `argv` devia ser declarado como `char **argv` ou `char *argv[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está percorrendo cada letra da senha, mas sim tentando converter a senha inteira em um número. A linha:

```
    k = atoi(argv[j]);
```

deveria ser:

```
    k = (int)argv[1][j]; // Caractere j do argumento 1
                         // Não use atoi, pois o que você quer é o valor do caractere em si
```

O erro é porque, como o tamanho de `argv` é `2`, a terceira iteração do loop tenta ler uma posição de memória que vai além dos limites do array, então dá a falha de segmentação.

Da mesma forma, a linha:

```
int m = strlen(argv);
```

deveria ser:

```
int m = strlen(argv[1]); // O tamanho da primeira palavra
```

No mais, seu código parece correto. Note no entanto que seu `k` não é um número de `0` a `26` (como na cifra de Vigenère original), mas sim o valor do caractere em si. Isso traz o efeito colateral da cifra ser sensível a maiúsculas e minúsculas (o original não diferencia capitalização). Se você quiser fazer da forma padronizada, precisará normalizar o valor de `k` antes de usá-lo. Exemplo:

```
    k = (int)argv[1][j];
    if ( 65 <= k && k <= 90 )
        k -= 65;
    else if ( 97 <= k && k <= 122 )
        k -= 97;
    else
        k = 0; // Caractere inválido na senha, ignore
```

P.S. Como apontado por Isac nos comentários, a forma como você está declarando `argv` também está incorreta - é pra ser um array de strings, não uma única string.

Comment: Me ajudou muito! Pra encerrar, só mais uma dúvida: _argv[]_ precisa ser uma lista bidimensional sempre? No código eu escrevi `char argv[]` porque na minha cabeça seria mais fácil trabalhar com uma lista simples de caracteres em vez de uma lista de strings.

Comment: C não é minha especialidade (só usei na faculdade, uns 15 anos atrás), então não posso dizer com certeza, mas eu acredito que sim. Quando se passam argumentos para um programa, eles são separados pelo sistema operacional mesmo, e apresentados ao C como uma lista de strings. O primeiro argumento é sempre o nome do programa, o segundo em diante são os argumentos separados por espaço. Assim, se você declarou `char *argv[]` e chamou seu programa como `meuprograma.exe teste etc`, `argv[0]` será a string `"meuprograma.exe"`, `argv[1]` será a string `"teste"`, `argv[2]` será `"etc"` e por aí vai.